# Using Session variable within foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to use `foreach` in cshtml file, and use the Session variable?

I want to do something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Session["Cart"])
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: Depends. What exactly is stored in the `Session["Cart"]`? because that will determine what you can do. Is it an array, or `List<[type]>`, or an `IEnumerable<[type]>`? Please be more specific as to what the context is.

Comment: @MGoward List ..

Comment: Okay that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(Session["Cart"] != null)
{
    foreach (var item in (Session["Cart"] as List<[type]>))
    {
       //do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

So the answer is yes

Comment: Thanks but I have a little problem now with this:
i have model called "Products" (whis is the 'type')
But it does not find it.. althought I do:  @model List<SurffingSite.Models.Products>

Comment: Can I see more of the code? that would help me out

Comment: Here is the html file: https://pastebin.com/YY01j1LX , here is the model: https://pastebin.com/c20X6Ufs

Comment: Well it looks like it should be working. I am not sure what could be done. I would suggest asking another question and seeing if others can give you an answer. I am sorry I was not able to help you any more...

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the object stored in `Session["Cart"]` implements either `IEnumerable` (which includes arrays and legacy collections) or `IEnumerable<T>` (which includes generic collections), you can use it in a `foreach` loop.

```
public void MyActionMethod()
{
    var list = Session["Cart"] as IEnumerable<Products>;
    if (list == null) throw new Exception("Cart not found or cannot be enumerated.");

    return View(list.ToList());
}
```

And in your cshtml:

```
@model List<Products>

@foreach (var product in Model)
{
    //Do something with product
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm having a little problem with it. Would you mind looking at my problem I described in the comment at the verified answer (above)?

Comment: You should probably pass in the list from the controller (as the model).  Then in your cshtml you'd use `@foreach (var item in Model)`.

Comment: I guess it's kind of indirect solution.. That's exactly what I did to overcome this problem but I thought there is direct solution. Thanks